# How to fix "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SUBJECT' not found"?

Tags: r

I am having a hard time `knitting` my `R markdown` because of this error

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SUBJECT' not found".

I tried rerunning the chunks from the very start but still it did not work. I am still a rookie of R so please bear with my question.

```
class(SUBJECT)
```

When I tried to run the chunk no problem occurred but when i tried to knit it, this issue comes in

> Quitting from lines 75-76 (exploratory-data-analysis-exercise.Rmd) 
>   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SUBJECT' not found
>   Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted

Comment: What is SUBJECT? What is it defined as? Your code is clearly not able to locate that object in your environment.

Comment: @makeshift-programmer here is the data SUBJECT
<int>
SEX
<fctr>
WEIGHT
<int>
HEIGHT
<dbl>
1 F 101 61.0 
2 F 112 61.0 
3 M 200 68.0 
4 F 110 59.0 
5 M 123 65.0 
6 F 125 62.0

Comment: Check the order in your document. Do you call SUBJECT before you create it? Try restarting your R session to make sure the script is reproducible.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes I tried calling it again using this code "names(data)" and this appears     [1] "SUBJECT" "SEX"     "WEIGHT"  "HEIGHT".... I also tried restarting it many times.. but still this issue comes up again "Error: object 'SUBJECT' not found"

Comment: Can you post your entire markdown document?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check what directory your files are currently stored at using getwd(), Then read your data from there. you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have : "eval=FALSE" in your R-Markdown chunks, especially the ones that you read your files (ie. read_csv), your codes do not get executed. So, the objects in your following chunks are not recognized.  Therefore, remove this code.

eval = FALSE prevents code from being evaluated. (And obviously if the code is not run, no results will be generated). This is useful for displaying example code, or for disabling a large block of code without commenting each line. https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-evaluation